# disable the click of disabled item in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor tag I want to prevent its click when it has an attribute="disabled".

```
 <a class="btn-rounded" disabled="disabled" id="Btn1" onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" onserverclick="UpdatePackage_Click" runat="server"></a>
```

I have tried below jQuery functions but didn't work for me:-

```
  $("body").on("click", ":disabled", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //return false;
            });

  if ($('a').is(':disabled')) {       
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: I am getting "Are you sure?" when I click on anchor..

Comment: maybe try to move inline code for onclick to that of jquery.
what i am thinking is that inline code is executed before jquerys

Comment: Then how can I manage that line as that is also the requirement, when its disable it should not work else it should work properly..

Comment: maybe write a function that checks if target of click is disabled, if its not then its calling the function passed as argument? then you could do $(elem).on("click", function(){ifNotDisabled(yourFoo)});